# How to correctly implement a while loop that reads a sequence of inputs?

Tags: c++

Write a while loop that sums all integers read from input until a negative integer is read. The negative integer should not be included in the sum.

Ex: If input is 20, 45, 34, 5, -44, then the output is:

104

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int numInput;
    int numInts;

    numInts = 0;
    cin >> numInput;

   while (numInput >= 0) {
      cout << numInts << endl;
      numInts = numInts + numInput;
   }

   cout << numInts << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you expect that loop to break when the only condition it depends on is based on a variable that is unchanged whatsoever during the loop body lifetime?

Comment: Perhaps you should read the input inside the loop itself?

Comment: `while(numInput >= 0)`
where do you change `numInput` in the loop to prevent a infinite loop?

Comment: @christopher1133 For the loop to terminate the variable `numInput` must become negative at some point inside the loop. There is no place in your code where that can happen because there is no code in the while loop that changes the value of `numInput`. The only statement that changes the value of `numInput` occurs before the while loop.

Comment: Try to explain the loop in great detail to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Especially tell it when and where the value of `numInput` will change, *inside the loop itself*.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that currently the condition inside the while loop doesn't depend on anything that you do inside the loop.

To solve this you can move the `cin >> numInput` to inside the condition as shown below:

```
int main() {
   int numInput;
   int sum = 0;
   //take input and check it
   while (cin >> numInput && numInput >= 0) {
      
      sum += numInput;
      std::cout <<"current sum is: "<<sum <<std::endl;
   }

   cout << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/tpHd9ka9L)

Answer (score 1):

The loop terminates when `numInput` is less than 0. In your code you read **only one number**. So if that number is greater than zero then you get an infinite loop **because you never read a second number**.

Your code should look something like this

```
cin >> numInput;         // read the first number
while (numInput >= 0) {
    cout << numInts << endl;
    numInts = numInts + numInput;
    cin >> numInput;     // read the next number
}
```

See how the above code reads a new number each time around the while loop. This way when a negative number is entered the loop will terminate.